# Why is doc.spans empty after spans are assigned to the doc object in Spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to convert a two-dimensional list with entity labels `(0, 1, -1)` into a `spaCy doc` object with `Spans` as entity labels. The 2-D list corresponds to token labels for the `tokens_` variable, which is basically a list of words. So basically, spans will have the start and end offsets for the tokens corresponding to the non-zero labels `(-1, 1)`.

I am trying to do it using the function `labelmatrix2doc`. However, even after assigning the spans to the doc object, it prints null lists without any spans.

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span, SpanGroup
    
def labelmatrix2doc(tokens_, token_offsets_, label_matrix):
    
    tokens_ = [token if token else ' ' for token in tokens_] # re-do empty tokens by adding a space
    doc = Doc( nlp.vocab, words=tokens_ )
    
    # Create a list of spaCy spans from the label matrix
    for i in range(len(label_matrix)):
        spans_i = []
        for j in range(len(label_matrix[i])):
            if label_matrix[i][j] != 0:
                start = token_offsets_[j]
                end = token_offsets_[j+1] if j < len(label_matrix[i])-1 else token_offsets_[j] + len(tokens_[j])
                span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=f'label_{label_matrix[i][j]}')
                spans_i.append(span)

        if spans_i:
            print( len(spans_i) )
            doc.spans[f"lf_{i}"] = spans_i
            print( doc.spans )
            
    
    return doc
```

Use the code below to simulate the inputs for the above function `def labelmatrix2doc(tokens_, token_offsets_, label_matrix)`.

```
import random
import string

# Set the size of the list
list_size = 10

# Generate a list of random English words
words_list = []
end_offsets_list = []
offset = 0
for i in range(list_size):
    word = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(3, 7)))
    words_list.append(word)
    offset += len(word)
    end_offsets_list.append(offset)

print(words_list)
print(end_offsets_list)

# Set the size of the array
array_size = 10

# Generate a 10x10 two-dimensional array filled with 0s, 1s, and -1s
two_d_array = []
for i in range(array_size):
    row = []
    for j in range(array_size):
        value = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
        row.append(value)
    two_d_array.append(row)

print(two_d_array)
```

Using the function on the simulated data prints null even though the spans of length 8, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 9 are generated.

```
labelmatrix2doc(words_list, end_offsets_list, two_d_array)
8
{'lf_0': []}
8
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': []}
4
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': []}
5
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': [], 'lf_3': []}
6
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': [], 'lf_3': [], 'lf_4': []}
7
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': [], 'lf_3': [], 'lf_4': [], 'lf_5': []}
7
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': [], 'lf_3': [], 'lf_4': [], 'lf_5': [], 'lf_6': []}
6
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': [], 'lf_3': [], 'lf_4': [], 'lf_5': [], 'lf_6': [], 'lf_7': []}
6
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': [], 'lf_3': [], 'lf_4': [], 'lf_5': [], 'lf_6': [], 'lf_7': [], 'lf_8': []}
9
{'lf_0': [], 'lf_1': [], 'lf_2': [], 'lf_3': [], 'lf_4': [], 'lf_5': [], 'lf_6': [], 'lf_7': [], 'lf_8': [], 'lf_9': []}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first transform the list of `spans` to `spangroups`.

The modified `labelmatrix2doc` is below.

```
def labelmatrix2doc(tokens_, token_offsets_, label_matrix):
    
    tokens_ = [token if token else ' ' for token in tokens_] # re-do empty tokens by adding a space
    doc = Doc( nlp.vocab, words=tokens_ )
    
    # Create a list of spaCy spans from the label matrix
    for i in range(len(label_matrix)):
        spans_i = []
        for j in range(len(label_matrix[i])):
            if label_matrix[i][j] != 0:
                start = token_offsets_[j]
                end = token_offsets_[j+1] if j < len(label_matrix[i])-1 else token_offsets_[j] + len(tokens_[j])
                span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=f'label_{label_matrix[i][j]}', alignment_mode='expand')
                spans_i.append(span)

        if spans_i:
            group = SpanGroup(doc, name=f"lf_{i}", spans=spans_i, attrs={"annotator": "matt"})
            doc.spans[f"lf_{i}"] = group
            print( doc.spans[f"lf_{i}"]  )
            
    
    return doc
```